# Private Inner Generic Class Implements Comparable(Missing Code)

Tags: java, generics, private, compareto

I cannot seem to figure out what the purpose of this Class/Method is. The program is supposed to count the frequency of words in a TXT file. The code in question is:

```
//Inner class inside of a public class
    private class Entry <T> implements Comparable<Entry<T>>{
            public T word;
            public int frequency;
            public Entry(T word, int f){
                this.word=word;
                frequency=f;
            }
            public int compareTo(Entry<T> e){
                /* insert your code */
            }
```

I have one arraylist that holds all of the words, I have a hashset with only unique words, and I have a method that counts the frequency of each word correctly. I need to only display the top 3 most frequent words. Which is what I am guessing this is used for since there is one arraylist left to use of the type `Entry<String>`(Which I believe is used to print the results). Im not sure what code is of use here, but if you need more I can post it no problem. I am really just trying to understand the purpose of this private inner class so that I can utilize it. Any help is appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Comment: You said you have a method that counts the frequency. What does it create? A HashMap<String, Integer>? or maybe an ArrayList<Entry<String>>?

Comment: The method is currently void, but i have a System.out.print function that allows me to see the values.It currently isn't putting those values anywhere. Would I want to add the values to an the ArrayList of the Entry<String> type in order to use this private class? This is the method you asked about.`private void count() {
        for (String key : wordSet) {    
 System.out.println(key + "," + Collections.frequency(wordList, key));
        }`

Comment: Yes you would want to store the `Name -> Frequency` pairs in an `ArrayList<Entry<String>>` to be then able to sort that list (by frequency) and then grab the top 3 entries from the list. This is where the `compareTo` method becomes relevant, because it specifies how the elements will be sorted. The rule here is to have `a.compareTo(b)` return `-1` is `a` is less than `b`, `0` if they are equal and `1` otherwise (examples: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/number_compareto.htm)

Comment: That makes a lot more sense. Thank you for your help!